# How to validate a token in OWIN in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC project in which I am trying to integrate OWIN authentication. I feel that I am almost there but maybe missing a couple of steps. My application has MVC views and also some legacy ASPX pages, along with several Web API controllers. I have a Startup.Auth.cs file with the following Configuration method.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // add a signin manager to the OWIN context
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
        });
    }
```

The AccountController has a Login method that looks like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

The PasswordSignInAsync method will eventually do a lookup in LDAP for the user credentials, but to simplify I am considering any input a success to start. The method looks like this:

```
    public override async Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = userName, UserName = userName, PasswordHash = password };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));

        this.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
        return SignInStatus.Success;
    }
```

The ApplicationUserManager class is empty because I am not storing any users. Everything will be retrieved from LDAP.
I am creating a user claim and calling AuthenticationManager.SignIn with that identity and returning Success. However, I get redirected back to the login page again. Is there something that I need to do to validate the incoming token? I can see when tracing web traffic that a token is being added to the cookies, but something is not right. Can anyone help me with the missing information? Thanks.

Comment: Add in `AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` immediately after your `SignIn` call. What does it show?

Comment: IsAuthenticated is false, so the SignIn is obviously failing. What happens during SignIn that would cause this to be true?

Comment: I changed the code new ClaimsIdentity() to new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie).

Comment: I solved the problem. When I create the identity with the following code, it works: var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); I guess creating the identity with the constructor that has the user name claim makes it valid in some way.